# Django Dashboard ControlCenter

Tags: python-3.x, django

estoy implementando Django Dashboard ControlCenter pero no entiendo muy bien como implementarlo.
Esta es la estructura de mi proyecto.
En clínica esta el archivo settings.py

[image: dashboard]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo dashboard.py esta al nivel del manage.py y contiene lo siguiente:

```
from controlcenter import Dashboard, widgets
from pacientes.models import *

class ModelItemList(widgets.ItemList):
    model = Pacientes
    list_display = ('pk', 'field')

class MyDashboard(Dashboard):
    widgets = (
        ModelItemList,
    )
```

En el settings.py he puesto esto:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'clinica',
'laboratorio',
'pacientes',
'medicos',
'examenes',
'django_pdb',
'resultados',
'reportlab',
'xlrd',
'numpy',
'reportes',
'openpyxl',
'dashing',
'controlcenter'
]

CONTROLCENTER_DASHBOARDS = (
    ('mydash', 'clinica.dashboards.MyDashboard'),
)
```

En url.py he puesto esto:

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   url(r'^laboratorio/', include(('laboratorio.urls', 'laboratorio'))),
   #url(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
   url(r'^pacientes/', include(('pacientes.urls', 'pacientes'))),
   url(r'^medicos/', include(('medicos.urls', 'medicos'))),
   url(r'^examenes/', include(('examenes.urls', 'examenes'))),
   url(r'^resultados/', include(('resultados.urls', 'resultados'))),
   url(r'^reportes/', include(('reportes.urls', 'reportes'))),
 # url(r'^dashboard/', include(router.urls)),
   url(r'^admin/dashboard/', controlcenter.urls),
]
```

Voy a la URL http://localhost:8000/admin/dashboard/mydash/ a ver si funciona y me aparece este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He seguido la documentación de este link: https://django-controlcenter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ , pero no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Hola roberto, SO en español es un sitio donde hay una comunidad dispuesta a ayudarte a encontrar la solución a un problema específico relacionado con la programación. Tienes algún problema intentando implementar Django ControlCenter? [Aquí](https://django-controlcenter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html) hay unos ejemplos prácticos en la documentación, puedes actualizar tu pregunta e indicarnos qué problemas presentas, de lo contrario es muy probable que reciba votos en contra y que sea puesta en espera

Comment: fijate que aqui " ('mydash', 'clinica.dashboards.MyDashboard')," debes colocar el nombre del *proyecto* y al parecer esta tomando el de tu app "*clinica*"